# Inverse transformation conditions

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $X$ to $Y$. We say that $T$ is invertible if there exists a function $S: Y \rightarrow X$ such that 
$$S(T(x)) = I(x) = x \text{ for all } x \in X$$ and
$$T(S(y)) = I(y) = y \text{ for all } y \in Y$$

However, my question is, say I found a candidate for the inverse transformation $S$, do I need to show both the above equalities hold or can I conclude $S$ is indeed the inverse transformation if only one of them hold? E.g., say I found $S(T(x)) = x$ for all $x \in X$, can I then conclude that $S$ is the inverse transformation of $T$ or do I still need to verify that the second equality hold before I can reach my conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**.

---

Take $X=\mathbb R$ and $Y=\mathbb R^2$.

Now, define $T(x)=(x,0)$ and define $S((x_1,x_2))=x_1$

Then, for all $x\in X$, you have $$S(T(x)) = S((x,0)) = x$$

However, it is not true that $T(S(y))=y$ is true for all $y\in Y$. For example, for $y=(1,1)$ you have $$T(S(y)) = T(S((1,1))) = T(1) = (1,0)\neq (1,1)=y$$

Comment: Should that say $S((x_1,x_2))=x_1$?

Comment: @bloomers Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $X=Y$ the real vector space of all real sequences and define

$T(x_1,x_2,....)= (0,x_1,x_2,...)$ and $S(x_1.x_2,...)=(x_2,x_3,...)$.

Then $S(T(x))=x$.

Comment: I can't decide whether your example (having $X=Y$) or mine (being finite-dimensional) is simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

If $S(T(x))=x$, then certainly $T(S(T(x))=T(x)$, which can be read $T(S(y))=y$, which seems to prove the claim.

But this is only valid if you cover all $y\in Y$, which may fail to be true with $y=T(x)$, unless $T$ is shown to be *surjective* (i.e. $T(X)=Y$).